# How to change map into a loop?

Tags: python

this question is probably really simple but it will help me to understand the difference between loop and map.
In the first example I managed to change it from:

```
    nrs = list(map(lambda x: int( open("img_" + str(x) + ".csv").readline().split(",")[1] ) , range(82))
```

to:

```
   nrs = [] 
   for x in range(82):
       nrs.append(int( open("img_" + str(x) + ".csv").readline().split(",")[1] ))
```

but how can I change:

```
    plt.plot(list(map(lambda x: ages[x], list(avg_si.keys() ))), list(avg_si.values()), 'ro', label='size')
```

into a loop?
I tried with:

```
srednia = []
for x in list(avg_si.values()):
     srednia.append(ages[x], list(avg_si.keys()))
plt.plot(srednia, "ro", label = "size")
```

But I get a KeyError

Comment: Can you post the full error traceback you get?

Comment: It is more pythonic to change a `map` to a list comprehension. Even if you want to change it to a loop, first changing it to a comprehension is a reasonable intermediate step.

Comment: @glibdud '
  File "C:/Users/misha/Documents/dae/dokument.py", line 52, in <module>
    srednia.append(ages[x], list(avg_si.keys()))

KeyError: 2.5355913274647888'

Comment: Can you post any plots for context?

Answer (score 0):

You should iterate over keys, not values.

```
    srednia = []
    for x in list(avg_si.keys()):
        srednia.append(ages[x], list(avg_si.values()))
    plt.plot(srednia, "ro", label = "size")
```

Comment: I got: 
TypeError: append() takes exactly one argument (2 given)

Comment: `list(avg_si.values())` is not a part of the `map` expression. It is just an argument to the function `plt.plot()`

Answer (score 0):

The expression

```
plt.plot(list(map(lambda x: ages[x], list(avg_si.keys() ))), list(avg_si.values()), 'ro', label='size')
```

is somewhat hard to parse. In addition to the last two string arguments you are passing it two lists:

```
1) list(map(lambda x: ages[x], list(avg_si.keys() )))
2) list(avg_si.values())
```

The second list requires no comment. The first one is the `map` expression. It is equivalent to the following list comprehension:

```
[ages[x] for x in avg_si.keys()]
```

Which would make the entire line equivalent to

```
plt.plot([ages[x] for x in avg_si.keys()], list(avg_si.values()), 'ro', label='size')
```

If you wanted to replace the comprehension by a loop you could do:

```
ageList = []
for x in avg_si.keys():
    ageList.append(ages[x])
```

and then:

```
plt.plot(ageList, list(avg_si.values()), 'ro', label='size')
```